# Trailing garbage Error in D3 parseSvg because of transition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm having an error when using D3 (version 4) in my visualization. Its basically a timeline on the x axis which visualizes documents. I have a main function which gets called on every zoom/brush event. It filters and updates the data and uses d3 enter/update/exit to update the SVG elements.

When zooming/brushing for some time D3 just crashes and shows the following error in a loop. It also happens randomly.

```
node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4250 Error: <g> attribute transform: Trailing garbage, "…41797761907139, 7.35527222388514…".
parseSvg @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4250
(anonymous) @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4299
(anonymous) @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:8324
tween @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:8363
start @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:8136
schedule @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:8085
timerFlush @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4949
wake @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4959
requestAnimationFrame (async)
sleep @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4996
nap @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4984
wake @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4962
requestAnimationFrame (async)
....
requestAnimationFrame (async)
sleep @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4996
nap @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4984
wake @ node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4962
node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4251 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matrix' of null
    at parseSvg (node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4251)
    at node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4299
    at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:8324)
    at SVGGElement.tween (node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:8363)
    at start (node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:8136)
    at schedule (node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:8085)
    at timerFlush (node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4949)
    at wake (node_modules\d3\build\node_modules\d3\build\d3.js:4959)
```

It seems that parsing the SVG is the error?

So I looked into the HTML and found that the source of the `parseSvg` error is this `g` element.

```
<g transform="translate(7.441797761907139, 7.355272223885149e-40)" style="opacity: 1; fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);">
```

Could the `e-40` at the end be at fault?

I tried to test this, and indeed, D3 crashes with `parseSvg` Error when a `e-40` is added to `translate()`.

The thing is, I am already using `.toFixed` to round to 2 decimal places right in the draw function (I also tried `Math.round()`). Yet, it still shows numbers without it (see second screenshot).

```
// ENTER
var contentEnter = dataJoin.enter()
    .append("g")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + (+d.cx).toFixed(2) + "," + (+d.cy).toFixed(2) + ")";
    });
```

[image: error message and html inspector]

Then I realized that the `cy` position of elements can change when zooming/brushing. I am using `.transition()` to update it.

```
contentEnter
    .merge(dataJoin)
    .transition()
    .duration(circleTransitionDuration)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .on("start", function repeat() {
        d3.active(this).attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + (+d.cx).toFixed(2) + "," + (+d.cy).toFixed(2) + ")";
        }).style("fill", function(d) {
            return d.color;
        }).transition();
    });
```

`circleTransitionDuration` is currently 50ms and updating the data and drawing takes about 10ms.

So what is happening? A new zoom event gets created, data updates and D3 draws. Then for some time the Animation is updated every frame until the transition is complete. It seems that before the transition is complete a new zoom/brush event is created and parses the incomplete SVG?

I tried to log the event with Google Chrome Profiler. Just before the error is thrown two `Animation Frame Fired` are called in the same `Frame`.

[image: google chrome profiler]

Just after that last `Animation Frame Fired` at `71005ms` D3 crashes and continues to show the error forever.

Can anyone help me identify where that error comes from and how to fix it?

Comment: There is no "incomplete SVG" when the error is thrown. Look at the [parseSvg](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate/blob/master/src/transform/parse.js) function: it creates a dummy element, sets the `transform` attribute and reads out the `transform.baseVal` property for further interpretation. The error occurs in line 21 when setting the attribute, which seems to be not well-formed. The source of that attribute is not what you set, but apparently the interpolated interim value while transition is underway. You are not setting a custom interpolator, are you?

Comment: The transform attribute that throws the error is not the one you see in the html, but the potential *next* value. Do you see a chance to get at the complete attribute string in the developer tools and not the excerpt the error message shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Update part of the D3 lifecycle from

```
// UPDATE
contentEnter
.merge(dataJoin)
.transition()
.duration(circleTransitionDuration)
.style("opacity", 1)
.on("start", function repeat() {
    d3.active(this).attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + (+d.cx).toFixed(2) + "," + (+d.cy).toFixed(2) + ")";
    }).style("fill", function(d) {
        return d.color;
    }).transition();
});
```

to

```
// UPDATE
contentEnter
.merge(dataJoin)
.style("opacity", 1)
.attr("transform", d => "translate(" + [d.cx, d.cy] + ")")
.transition()
.duration(circleTransitionDuration);
```

and now I can't reproduce this anymore. It seems the anonymous function was causing problems.